# Generic Types of a Wrapper Factory Method

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a factory method for wrappers and I am stumbling over the generic types.

I have two Classes A and B, where B derives from A. Then I have a Wrappber base class (WBase) and 
wrapper classes WA and WB for A and B.

When compiling the code below, I get a

> Type safety: Unchecked invocation wrap(Class, Test.B) of the generic method wrap(Class, T) of type Test

warning on the invocation of the wrap method? Any Idea how to do it right?

Cheers

```
public class Test {

    public class A {
    }

    public class B extends A {
    }

    public class WBase<T> {
    }

    public class WA<T extends A> extends WBase<T> {
    }

    public class WB extends WA<B> {
    }

    public <T, W extends WBase<T>> W wrap(Class<W> cls, T item) {
        return null;
    }

    public void test() {
        B b = new B();
        wrap(WA.class, b);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I've just solved my problem! :-) The solution I found is to introduce an additional wrapper class WABase and let WA extend from that class, and remove the generic parameter from WA:

```
public class WABase<T extends A> extends WBase<T> {} 
public class WA extends WBase<A> {} 
public class WB extends WABase<B> {}
```

In addition I redefined the wrap method to

```
<T, W extends WBase<? super T>> W wrap(Class<W> cls, T item)
```

Now It all works fine:

```
B b = new B(); 
A a = new A(); 
wrap(WB.class, b); 
// wrap(WB.class, a); // does not compile, which is right 
wrap(WA.class, a); 
wrap(WA.class, b);
```

Thanks to morgano and newacct for pushing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in this part:

```
wrap(WA.class, b)
```

WA is a parameterized class, when you use *WA.class*, you are using a "raw" type.

Comment: I've just solved my problem! :-) The solution I found is to introduce an additional wrapper class WABase and let WA extend from that class, and remove the generic parameter from WA:

public class WABase<T extends A> extends WBase<T> {}
public class WA extends WBase<A> {}
public class WB extends WABase<B> {}

In addition I redefined the wrap method to 

<T, W extends WBase<? super T>> W wrap(Class<W> cls, T item)

Now It all works fine:

B b = new B();
A a = new A();
wrap(WB.class, b);
// wrap(WB.class, a); // does not compile, which is right
wrap(WA.class, a);
wrap(WA.class, b);

Answer (score 2):

You can cast around the fact that `WA.class` is `Class<WA>` and not `Class<WA<B>>` like you want:

```
wrap((Class<WA<B>>)(Class<?>)WA.class, b);
```

Of course, you will get unchecked cast warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Since `b` is of type `B`, then in your `wrap(WA.class, b)` invocation `T` is `B`.
Since `T` is `B`, then the typed variable of the `Class` instance passed as the first argument has to extend `WBase<B>`. The typed varialble of `WA.class` is `WA` which apparently *does extend `WBase<T>`*.

But the `T` in `public class WA<T extends A> extends WBase<T>` **isn't the `T` in `public <T, W extends WBase<T>> W wrap(Class<W> cls, T item)`**. These are two separate independent `T`s. If you switch one of the `T`s with, say, `S`, you'll see it can still be compiled.